# Unknown output appended whenever running 'java' command in CMD/Shell

Tags: java

Recently whenever i am running any command related to 'java' , I see lots of unknowns lines getting appended with output I am not sure from where it is coming

e.g.
❯ java .\FutureOutput.java

```
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.floor(D)D], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.ceil(D)D], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.rint(D)D], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.copySign(FF)F], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.copySign(DD)D], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.signum(D)D], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.signum(F)F], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Submitting Callable
Do something else while callable is getting executed
Retrieve the result of the future
Entered Callable
Hello from Callable
```

Here is the output for java -version

```
java -version
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.floor(D)D], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.ceil(D)D], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.rint(D)D], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.copySign(FF)F], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.copySign(DD)D], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.signum(D)D], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [java.lang.Math.signum(F)F], but the method is not annotated with @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Machine (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-machine)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Machine (build 11.0.12+7-LTS-machine, mixed mode)
```

I couldn't understand what do these lines refer to? Any way I can stop this as it is quite annoying?

Comment: It seems some kind of corruption in the native JDK's library "Math". Some methods which are supposed to be annotated as HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate are not and the java executable raises you a warning about it each time you start it. I'd try first by re-installing the JDK and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Try add @HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate annotation in the method.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Spot-on!! It worked .Thanks .